# DonationAlerts API C#

Tags: c#, api

Как получить сообщение о донате на C#
Нашел код на Java он работает через сокет, но я не смог перенести его на C#

[Java код](https://github.com/Iaiao/interactive-donations/blob/master/mc/iaiao/interactivedonations/InteractiveDonations.java)

Выдает ошибку:

```
Quobject.EngineIoClientDotNet.Client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error --- 
> System.AggregateException: Произошла одна или несколько ошибок. ---> 
System.Net.WebException: Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (400) 
Недопустимый запрос.
в System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
в Quobject.EngineIoClientDotNet.Client.Transports.PollingXHR.XHRRequest. 
<Create>b__7_0()
в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean 
includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, 
CancellationToken cancellationToken)
в Quobject.EngineIoClientDotNet.Client.Transports.PollingXHR.XHRRequest.Create()
--- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
```

Код:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var socket = IO.Socket("http://socket.donationalerts.ru:443/");
        MyRequest mr = new MyRequest()
        { token = "token", type = "minor" };

        socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Подключено");
            socket.Emit("add-user", mr);
            socket.Emit("donation");
        });
        socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, (data) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка CONNECTION\n" + data);
        });
        socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка TIMEOUT");
        });
        socket.On("donation", (data) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());
        });
        socket.On("update", (data) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type:   {0}\r\n", data);
        });
        socket.Connect();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MyRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("token")]
    public string token { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    public string ToJsonString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
    public static MyRequest Deserialize(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRequest>(jsonString);
    }
}
```

Использую библиотеку https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet

Comment: О чём именно речь? Дополните вопрос, нужно как можно больше деталей.

Comment: Вставьте код текстом, скришоты кода бесполезны и не приветствуются здесь. Вы не смогои перенести на C#, в чем именно возникли трудности? От того что вы вставили кусок Java када в .NET приложение, оно конечно не заработает.

Comment: @aepot проблема на данный момент с подключением к сокету

Comment: Так и быть, я написал в поисковике "C# Socket" и нашел вам ответ в первой же ссылке https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @aepot мой код должен подключаться и вывести "Подключено" при подключений но этого не происходит

Comment: Что такое `IO.Socket`, что за библиотека? Я знаю только `System.Net.Sockets.Socket`.

Comment: У вас опечатка в адресе, порт 443 должен быть, а не 433. Внимательнее надо быть.

Comment: @aepot да IO.Socket это библиотека https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet, исправил порт, появилась новая ошибка System.ArgumentException: "Could not determine JSON object type for type DonationAlersAPI.MyRequest."

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не должны вызывать `Emit` раньше, чем `Connect`. Занесите код обратно в обработчик события.

Comment: @aepot тогда выдает Ошибка CONNECTION

Comment: Ну теперь хоть до ошибки подключения дошло, а раньше не доходило. Вы хоть понимаете что такое делегаты и в каком порядке здесь выполняется код? Если нет, попробуйте выполнить код пошагово, либо поставьте точки останова.

Comment: @aepot добавил скриншот ошибки

Comment: Ошибку вставьте текстом. Чтобы она отформатировалась, добавьте в начало каждой строчки 4 пробела или ``` такие символы в начале и конце текста ошибки.

Comment: @aepot Добавил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решено, замените `http://socket.donationalerts.ru:443` на `wss://socket.donationalerts.ru:443`

Comment: `Web Socket SSL`