# C# DonationAlerts не получаю сообщения о донате

Tags: c#, сокет

Добавлял сообщения через мой сообщения, и тестовое оповещение

Использую библиотеку: Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client

Токен пробывал из OAuth приложения, и из основных настроек.

Проблема в заголовке

Подключение с двумя токенами проходит отлично.

Код:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var socket = IO.Socket("wss://socket.donationalerts.ru:443");
        if (socket != null)
        {
            MyRequest mr = new MyRequest()
            { token = "token", type = "minor" };

            socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, (fn) =>
            {
                socket.Emit("add-user", mr.ToJsonString());
                socket.Emit("update");
                socket.Emit("donation");
                Console.WriteLine("Подключено");
            });
            socket.On("update", (data) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Type:   {0}\r\n", data);
            });
            socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, (data) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка CONNECTION\n" + data);
            });
            socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка TIMEOUT");
            });
            socket.On("donation", (donate) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("New donation 1");
                Console.WriteLine(donate.ToString());
            });
            socket.Connect();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Socket равен null");
        }
    }

    private static void Call(Object args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MyRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("token")]
    public string token { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    public string ToJsonString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
    public static MyRequest Deserialize(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRequest>(jsonString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211231/donationalerts-api-c

Comment: @PavelPopov не дубликат.

Answer (score 0):

Как мне удалось узнать, для вебсокета `donationalerts` нужно рукопожатие, особое, для этого мне пришлось сделать некоторые действия:

Сначала, оправляем *get* запрос на адрес

```
https://socket2.donationalerts.ru/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1234567
```

в `t` нужно подставить рандомное значение. Получаем `sid`, парсим его и уже делаем запрос *POST* с `sid`

```
https://socket2.donationalerts.ru/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1234567&sid=your_sid
```

и в content запихиваем строку с токеном

```
"69:42[\"add-user\",{\"token\":\"Your_token\",\"type\":\"alert_widget\"}]"
```

Отправляем, и уже можно подключаться через `websocket` с параметром `t` и `sid`.

Поэтому для донатов пришлось писать свой класс.